# How to make a button invisible when clicked in java?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, actionlistener

I am working on a project from a textbook and I'm stuck.
The goal is: When the GUI first appears, both buttons are visible, but when one button is clicked, that button disappears and only the other button is visible. Thereafter only one button is visible; when the button is clicked, it disappears and the other button appears

```
public class ButtonDemo extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    public static final int WIDTH = 400;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 300;

    public ButtonDemo()
    {
        setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        WindowDestroyer listener = new WindowDestroyer();
        addWindowListener(listener);

        Container contentPane = getContentPane();
        contentPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        contentPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JButton sunnyButton = new JButton("Sunny");
        sunnyButton.addActionListener(this);
        contentPane.add(sunnyButton);
        JButton cloudyButton = new JButton("Cloudy");
        cloudyButton.addActionListener(this);
        contentPane.add(cloudyButton);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String actionCommand = e.getActionCommand();
        Container contentPane = getContentPane();

        if(actionCommand.equals("Sunny"))
        {
            contentPane.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        }

        else if (actionCommand.equals("Cloudy"))
        {
            contentPane.setBackground(Color.GRAY);


        }
        else
            System.out.println("Error in button interface.");
    }
}
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? There is a setVisible(boolean) method that seems to be a good start

Comment: I have tried to use the setVisible method in the if statement of each sunny and cloudy but it closes the application when i just write serVisible(false)

Comment: @Infested I'm pretty sure with swing, the button will repaint itself

Comment: @Cruncher may be, but the frame isnt and thats what its painted on. if the buttons were static you wouldnt need to repaint the whole thing.

Comment: @Infested Swing takes care of it all for you. I promise.

Comment: 1) For many components in one space, use a [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as seen in this [short example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556). 2) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Answer (score 3):

Using setVisible on the buttons should work. Try the following:

Move the following lines to the fields of ButtonDemo:

```
JButton sunnyButton = new JButton("Sunny");
JButton cloudyButton = new JButton("Cloudy");
```

Change the if statements in your `actionPerformed` to:

```
if(actionCommand.equals("Sunny"))
{
    contentPane.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    sunnyButton.setVisible(false);
    cloudyButton.setVisible(true);
}
else if (actionCommand.equals("Cloudy"))
{
    contentPane.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    sunnyButton.setVisible(true);
    cloudyButton.setVisible(false);
}
```

Comment: It has an error saying sunnyButton or cloudyButton cannot be resolved

Comment: @user2668069 did you put them into the fields of ButtonDemo?

Comment: Thats because theyre not members of the class so you cant call them by using the name you used inside the constructor.

Comment: How do I put them into the fields of ButtonDemo

Comment: @user2668069 the two lines that I specified, put them right below your width and height lines

Comment: How do you mean Cruncher

Comment: @user2668069 `JButton sunnyButton = new JButton("Sunny");
JButton cloudyButton = new JButton("Cloudy");` put these lines below `public static final int HEIGHT = 300;`

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple code. Make `sunnyButton` and `cloudyButton` as instance member.

Simply check for the source of the action event and hide the source component and show the other one.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if (sunnyButton == e.getSource()) {
        sunnyButton.setVisible(false);
        cloudyButton.setVisible(true);
    } else if (cloudyButton == e.getSource()) {
        sunnyButton.setVisible(true);
        cloudyButton.setVisible(false);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I tried that but the button did not dissapear though, i made sunnyButton and cloudyButton instance variables of class ButtonDemo

Comment: Find the [CODE here](http://ideone.com/MH58N7) and validate with your code or try this one.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
source.setVisible(false)
```

to hide and

```
source.setVisible(true)
```

to show the buttons?

Edit:
You should get the source of the event (e.getSource()) and hide it

Comment: You want to hide the contentPane?

Comment: @Cruncher: You are right, you should hide the sources (buttons) not the pane.

Comment: This is a little bit better. But you still need a way to get the other button.

Comment: It works, but I need to make one true and the other false for each if statement

Comment: @user2668069: do not forget to give credit to Cruncher's answer and accept it.